# Macbook screen randomly becomes undimmed (Automatically Adjust Brightness is off)

Tags: macbook-pro, display, screen

I like to dim my mac fully to 0 sometimes, usually when I'm plugged into HDMI to use a monitor or TV. However, at random intervals, the screen will light up again (at brightness level 1). It's a small annoyance but it can mean having to cross the room to dim it again, or live with two screens on at the same time, which I cannot do.

Most of what I find online tells me to disable "Automatically Adjust Brightness," but I've always had it disabled. Again, this happens randomly, sometimes multiple times in a row, and nothing is being done to the computer at the time (no charging cable, etc.)

It's a 16" 2021 Macbook Pro running Monterey. Any ideas on this would be appreciated!

Comment: Yeah, usually I'll be using it as a video player. I like closing the MacBook and using clamshell mode sometimes, but other times I still want access to the keyboard if needed, and often want to dim the screen and have it stay dimmed

Answer (score -1):

its an apple bug/conflict.
sometimes when my screen brightness is turned down,
my screen will just randomly go full 100% brightness.
(& the auto dimming is off, of course)

also, i use an hdmi cable to my tv, but macOS now doesn’t allow me to turn the brightness off on my mac all the way anymore,
which makes no sense…